# Sauce Labs badge showing unknown karma.js

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, karma-runner, saucelabs

When including the [Status Badge](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Using+Status+Badges+and+the+Browser+Matrix+Widget+to+Monitor+Test+Results) in a project's `README.md` file using:

```
[![Sauce Test Status](https://saucelabs.com/buildstatus/YOUR_SAUCE_USERNAME)](https://saucelabs.com/u/YOUR_SAUCE_USERNAME)
```

It is displaying this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image: Sauce Labs Passing]

Relevant `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file:

```
"karma": "^1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-sauce-launcher": "^1.1.0",
```

Relevant config settings in the `karma.conf.js` file:

```
singleRun: process.env.CI,
sauceLabs: {
  testName: 'Web App Tests'
},
customLaunchers: customLaunchers,
reporters: process.env.CI ? ['dots', 'saucelabs'] : ['progress']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by **adding** the **build version** to the `karma.conf.js` file:

```
    singleRun: process.env.CI,
    sauceLabs: {
      build: require('./package.json').version, // New
      testName: 'Web App Tests'
    },
    customLaunchers: customLaunchers,
    reporters: process.env.CI ? ['dots', 'saucelabs'] : ['progress']
```